# Creating/Deploying Windows Server 2019 Image on multiple servers

Tags: installation, deployment, windows-server-2019, disk-image, clone

I manage servers that are all identical in terms of hardware and software. The only differences are hostnames and IP addresses. I've been researching how to clone the OS across these to speed up deployments, but I am having trouble since a lot of examples use VMs whereas all my servers are physical boxes.

My goal is to take the config - which consists of some registry tweaks, local group policy changes, and minimal basic software (like notepad++) - and clone that exact image onto other servers that have the same exact hardware. None of these machines will be on a domain or use Active Directory.

Is there a way to do this on Server 2019 without using 3rd party software?

Answer (score 1):

WIM - Windows Imaging Format. Make your golden image however you'd like, capture it, deploy as desired.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format

If you find out that you need to support disparate hardware, you can also use DISM to inject the extra drivers.

Comment: Awesome. Going to give this a try!